# J2ME elements styling in a loop

Tags: forms, java-me, styling

In a J2ME project I want to set all elements with the same type to the same styling. At the moment I have to set them one by one. Just thinking if there is a way to go through all the elements of the same type in a loop. And the project has like a dosen forms.

Anyone?

Comment: What do you mean same style? Generally the looks of Form elements are decided by the individual device.

Comment: By styling I mean text size and item alignments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about standard java-me lcdui forms (and not a special toolkit like lwuit.),
you have two options:

1. just put all the form elements you want to style in a vector when you create them.
   this is useful if you have different types of items, like text, button, and want to style them differently.
2. use `Form.size()` amd `Form.getItem()` to iterate over your form elements.

Option 2 can look like this:

```
void centerItems(Form myForm){
    int nrElems = myForm.size;
    for(int i = 0; i<nrElems; i++){
        Item item = myForm.get(i);
        item.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am talking about standard java-me lcdui forms. Yor suggested option number two looks more atractive 'cos it may mean less code. However to really benefit from such code I need to be able to go through all the forms in a loop. Like we can do with HTML DOM objects.